# Error rate not returning any data when grouped by HTTP status

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have a graph in Grafana using a Prometheus data source for displaying the error rates from my API.  This is working fine with this query:

```
sum(rate(va_request_response_code{endpoint="api", statusCode!="200"}[5m])) by (exported_endpoint, statusCode)
```

I get the rate of non-200 response codes from my API and then sum those rates as I have 3 instances of my API running.  I then group these by `exported_endpoint` (the actual path a user requested) and `statusCode` which is the exact HTTP status code returned.

Although this is a little useful as a raw number it is not that helpful.  Having 100 errors per second out of 100 requests is very bad, having 100 errors out of 1,000,000 requests is less of an issue.  Therefore I wanted to divide by the total number of requests but am struggling.  If I do:

```
(sum(rate(va_request_response_code{endpoint="api", statusCode!="200"}[5m])) by (exported_endpoint, statusCode))/(sum(rate(va_request_response_code{endpoint="api"}[5m])) by (exported_endpoint))
```

Then it just displays `No data points` which makes sense as in the first case it is grouping by statusCode in the dividend and not in the divisor so it must mean that it is trying to find matches before dividing. Instead doing this does work:

```
(sum(rate(va_request_response_code{endpoint="api", statusCode!="200"}[5m])) by (exported_endpoint))/(sum(rate(va_request_response_code{endpoint="api"}[5m])) by (exported_endpoint))
```

But I then lose the grouping by status code which I want.  Ideally I would like to know that x% of the requests return `404` and y% return `500`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to write it like this:

```
sum by (exported_endpoint, statusCode) (rate(va_request_response_code{endpoint="api", statusCode!="200"}[5m]))
  / ignoring(statusCode) group_left
sum by (exported_endpoint) (rate(va_request_response_code{endpoint="api"}[5m]))
```

I.e. take the two vectors, left one with a `statusCode` label, right one without; divide them ignoring the `statusCode` label; then apply the labels of the left vector to the result.

Here's [the link](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) to the Prometheus documentation of many-to-one and one-to-many matching in PromQL.